# Умножение в столбик C++

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь реализовать умножение строковых чисел стобиком. На вход подается два числа, записанные в string. Потом я их перевожу в массив и дальше пытаюсь сделать умножение. Уже несколько раз проанализировал алгоритм и не могу найти ошибку. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a, n;
    int* A, *B, *C, length, l, cc;
    //cin>>a;
    //cin>>n;
    a = "1";
    n = "1";
    A = new int [a.size()];
    B = new int [n.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        A[i] = a[a.size() - i - 1] - '0';

    for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
        B[i] = n[n.size() - i - 1] - '0';

    length = a.size() + n.size() + 1 ;
    l = length;
    C = new int [length];

    for (int ix = 0; ix < a.size() - 1; ix++)
        for (int jx = 0; jx < n.size() - 1; jx++)
        {
            C[ix + jx - 1] += A[ix] * B[jx];
            cc == A[ix] * B[jx];
        }

    for (int ix = 0; ix < length; ix++)
    {
        C[ix + 1] +=  C[ix] / 10;
        C[ix] %= 10;
    }

    while (C[length] == 0)
        length-- ;

    for (int i = l - 1; i > -1; i--)
        cout << C[i];

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Должно хватить

```
length = a.size() + n.size() - 1;
```

Еще массив `C` у вас неинициализирован, в нем случайные числа. Его после создания надо обнулить.

И выводите вы его не так - уменьшаете `length`, а в цикле используете `l`.

Еще - циклы умножения у вас слишком короткие.

Я попытался исправить ваши ошибки:

```
int main()
{
    string a,n;
    int *A, *B, *C, length, l,cc;
    cin>>a;
    cin>>n;
    //a="1";
    //n="1";
    A=new int [a.size()];
    B=new int [n.size()];

    for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
        A[i]=a[a.size()-i-1]-'0';
    for (int i=0; i<n.size(); i++)
        B[i]=n[n.size()-i-1]-'0';

    length = a.size() + n.size() - 1 ;
    l=length;
    C=new int [length];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < length; ix++)
    {
        C[ix] = 0;
    }

    for (int ix = 0; ix < a.size(); ix++)
    {
        for (int jx = 0; jx < n.size(); jx++)
        {
            C[ix + jx] += A[ix] * B[jx];
        }
    }

    for (int ix = 0; ix < length-1; ix++)
    {
        C[ix + 1] +=  C[ix] / 10;
        C[ix] %= 10;
    }

    while (C[length] == 0)
        length-- ;
    for(int i=length; i>-1; i--)
        cout<<C[i];

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но вывод у меня был сделан верно:for(int i=length-1; i>-1; i--)
        cout<<C[i];. В ином случае затрагивает пустое значение массива и выводит неверный ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз на свой исходник - вы выводите не от `length`, а от `l`! Что я и написал - вы меняете `length`, но выводите-то, начиная с `l`, которое не меняли!

Answer (score -1):

> Уже несколько раз проанализировал алгоритм и не могу найти ошибку.

Как минимум, тут:

> ```
> cc==A[ix] * B[jx];
> ```

должно быть `=`, а не `==`.

Остальное читать лень.