# Умножение двух двоичных чисел с++

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать как написать код для умножения двух двоичных чисел? Нужно именно их умножить, поэтому через перевод в 10 сс не получится.

Comment: В каком виде они представлены?

Comment: в смысле? я ввожу два десят. числа перевожу из в двоичные и должен их перемножить.

Comment: Что для вас значит "перевожу в двоичные"?

Comment: @Harry ну представляю их в виде единиц и нулей.

Comment: Строкой? Массивом int? палочками и кружочками на бумаге? Напишите для начала этот код перевода.

Comment: массивом
cin » N; 
while (N > 0) 
{ 
s += N % 2 + '0'; 
N /= 2; 
} 
l = s.length(); 
cout« "Число в двоичной системе: " « endl; 
for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) 
{ 
cout « s[l-i-1]; 
}

Comment: Это строка, а не массив... ну, неважно. Посмотрите [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595986/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BA-c) - тут как раз занимаются перемножением чисел, записанных строками. Учтите только, что у вас таблица умножения гораздо короче :), а при сложении 1+1 = 10.

Comment: @Harry Извиняюсь за наглость, но не подскажите мне что мне нужно сделать чтобы тот код нормально перемножал двоичные числа? Я уже три часа голову ломаю над этим.... Причем некоторые он перемножает верно а некоторые нет... Чувствую себя нереально тупым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну держите... Я не стал, как там, делать - работал без промежуточных массивов, прямо со строками...

```
string mul(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    string r(a.length()+b.length()-1,'0');
    for (int i = a.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = b.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            r[i+j] += (a[i] != '0' && b[j] != '0');
        }
    }
    for (int i = r.length()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        r[i-1] += (r[i]-'0')/2;
        r[i] = (r[i]-'0')%2 + '0';
    }
    while(r[0] > '1')
    {
        r = "0" + r;
        r[0] += (r[1]-'0')/2;
        r[1] = (r[1]-'0')%2 + '0';
    }
    return r;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << mul("1001","1001") << endl;
    cout << mul("101","111") << endl;
    cout << mul("1000","101") << endl;
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь что задаю глупый вопрос, но не могли бы вы мне пояснить почему вот тут r[i+j] += (a[i] != '0' && b[j] != '0'); Мы пишем != '0'? Я просто делаю сейчас похожую программу только для сложения и деления и не понимаю почему у меня не работает...

Comment: @Roman Ну, просто там будет добавляться единица только при произведении единиц. Т.е. когда `a[i]` и `b[j]` - единицы. Я просто предпочел везде сравнивать с нулем.

Comment: то есть для сложения надо будет писать: r[i] += (a[i] == '1' || b[i] == '1') ?
предположим что a и b одинаковой длины

Comment: При сложении нужно еще переносы учитывать.